# Ruby Options Parser with list of input values

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I am new to ruby and working on a script with command line options.

I need to specify a list of valid input values(String) for a field.

Is there a concise way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) then you end up with a list of arguments, and from that you can presume the first is a command.

To validate it you typically do this:

```
case (command)
when 'action'
  do_action
when 'other'
  do_other
else
  $stderr.puts "#{command.inspect} is not a valid command."
  exit(-1)
end
```